# didSelectRowAt from custom cell do nothing

Tags: swift, uitableview, custom-cell, didselectrowatindexpath

below code supposed to call usernames from an array and user able to tap on the desired username. call to that array is a success and I can see the usernames but won't able to tap into it. and it don't even print "didSelectRowAt". appreciate your help. thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MentionUserCell

    cell.username!.text = autoComplete[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return autoComplete.count
}



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

    let selectedCell: MentionUserCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! MentionUserCell
    let selectedWord: String = selectedCell.username!.text! + " "
    print("didSelectRowAt")
    var string: NSString = NSString(string: self.commentTextView.text!)
    string = string.replacingCharacters(in: otoCadang.sharedInstance.foundRange, with: selectedWord) as NSString

    // change text field value
    commentTextView.text = string as? String

    // change cursor position
    let positionOriginal = commentTextView.beginningOfDocument
    if let cursorLocation: UITextPosition = self.commentTextView.position(from: positionOriginal, offset: otoCadang.sharedInstance.foundRange.location + selectedWord.characters.count)
    {
        self.commentTextView.selectedTextRange = self.commentTextView.textRange(from: cursorLocation, to: cursorLocation)
    }



    // remove suggestion
    self.autoComplete.removeAll()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? just add a breakpoint in the `didSelectRowAt` and check what's happening...

Comment: Make sure table's selection mode isn't set to `No Selection`

Comment: Is this a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController` with a table you added? If the latter, did you set the table view's `delegate`?

Comment: @rmaddy yes already set the delegate viewDidLoad. and i set this as an extension - extension CaptionViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

Comment: @AhmadF how to properly debug?i'm new at this. i did put print("didSelectRowAt") there, so i'm aware didSelectRow do nothing.

Comment: Check two things in your code 
1. Table view selection mode, make it true if false 
2. Did you applied tap gesture on your view controller? if yes then remove it. hope it will work for you . if you get not solved then please let me know am here to help you!

Comment: @MuseerAnsari yes this works when i removed tap gesture. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check List**

1. tableview delegate is set properly
2. tableview selection mode == No Selection, then change to single selection
3. function name is correct `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`
4. are you using any tap gesture on this view? remove it.

Comment: yes done that & success. seems like it was because of tap gesture. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing `UITextView` will can't call to `didselectRowAt. Try to get the Your MentionUserCell, IndexPath in UITextView's methods and handle there. Example:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
     var parentView = textView as UIView
     while !(parentView is UITableViewCell) {
         parentView = parentView.superview!
      }
      if let cell: MentionUserCell = parentView as? MentionUserCell {
          if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
              let yourIndexPath = indexPath
          }
      }
      //your code 
 }
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When are using two or more cells the didSelectRow method is not working Well. You can use a button in cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifierName", for: indexPath) as! MentionUserCell

    cell.username!.text = autoComplete[indexPath.row]


    let button = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UIButton
    button.cellclick.addTarget(self, action: #selector(functionName(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
    return cell

}
```

Now you get the indexPath:-

```
func functionName(sender:UIButton)  {
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableview)
    let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```